# php while loop with condition check by array

Tags: php, while-loop

I've two arrays suppose:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(3,4,5,6);
```

Now I've to do something while all `$a` element is exactly equals to array `$b`

Comment: I'm not really understand the question...

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want to compare single elements in `$a` against single elements in `$b`? Do you want to compare the whole arrays (then you would not need a while loop)? Your current statement sounds like you wanted to compare each element in `$a` against `$b`. That does not seem to be sense, an element is never equal to a whole array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `array_diff()`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you could do here in my mind.

A VERY simple and basic way would be to loop through and have some logic in there to check if $a[$val] == $b[$val] and if it is do something, otherwise not.

Like the good people above said, there is a function in PHP called array_diff() which computes the difference in arrays. The below example is taken from the PHP.net site.

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>

Multiple occurrences in $array1 are all treated the same way. This will output :

Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

So it depends on exactly what you want to do. If you wish to make your statement more clear then please do so and I will try to re-answer accordingly.

Thanks